# No output in Java

Tags: java

I am learning Java, I am trying to create a class and instantiate it. But I am not getting any output when I execute the below code in Eclipse.

package day1;

```
class student {
    int mark1 = 0;
    int mark2 = 0;
    int mark3 = 0;
    int total = 0;

    void bio(int newmark) {
        mark1 = mark1 + newmark;

    }

    void chemistry(int newmark) {
        mark2 = mark2 + newmark;

    }

    void maths(int newmark) {
        mark3 = mark3 + newmark;

    }

    void printmarks() {
        System.out.println(mark1 + mark2 + mark3);

    }
}

public class May24 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        student student1 = new student();
        student student2 = new student();
        student1.bio(10);
        student1.chemistry(20);
        student1.maths(30);

        student2.bio(40);
        student2.chemistry(30);
        student2.maths(40);
    }

}
```

Can some one point out where am I wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you want to call `printmarks` somewhere.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: `printmarks()` prints the sum of the three marks instead of each of mark which I think you are expecting. Modify like: `System.out.println(mark1 + " " + mark2 + " " + mark3);`

Comment: Tip: In java, there is the convention in write classes in upper case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because whatever you did is, just assigning values to class data member, you haven't call `printmarks()` to print output.
add following lines to your main()

```
student1.printmarks();
student2.printmarks();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        student student1 = new student();
        student student2 = new student();
        student1.bio(10);
        student1.chemistry(20);
        student1.maths(30);
        student1.printmarks();

        student2.bio(40);
        student2.chemistry(30);
        student2.maths(40);
        student2.printmarks();

    }
```